# Isn't the Church-Turing-Deutsche (CTD) Principle an empirical question?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-computer

The Church-Turing-Deutsche (CTD) Principle is the idea that all physical processes are computable by a quantum computer (i.e. quantum Turing machine).

Before I knew this idea had a name, I always thought this was the case since all physical phenomena boil down to the unitary transformation and measurement of quantum systems(?). And indeed, all a quantum algorithm is is a series of unitary transforms and measurements on a quantum system. What finite realizable physical system could possibly be *un*computable?

But reading the literature gives me the sense that there are multiple opinions on this despite me thinking that this is an empirical question. What am I missing here?

*P.S. I was going to post this in the quantum computing stack exchange but thought that this question is less about quantum computing/information/algorithms and more about quantum physics in general.*

*P.P.S. By computable I am strictly talking about just that, computable. Not efficiently computable.*

Comment: Good question!  It would be helpful to distinguish, though, between "computable" and "efficiently computable."  Someone will doubtless post a better answer than I can, but taking the idea of a quantum computer sufficiently broadly it should probably be the case that physically processes are *computable*, almost by definition.  But *efficiently computable* is another question entirely, and places much more stringent restrictions on the types of problems we can address, although these constraints are also not completely understood.

Comment: I agree, and I indeed meant *computable* and not the more specific *efficiently computable*. I'll edit the question to make this clear.